# Clang Static Analyzer и проект в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang

Возможно ли, и если возможно, то как (хотя бы в общих чертах) прикрутить *Clang Static Analyzer* для проверки проекта студии. Провозился сегодня весь день, пытался искать в интернете, собрал *Clang* по [инструкции](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#build), но как запустить проверку с помощью `scan-build` не очень понятно. Параллельно использую `cppcheck`, там можно ключом задать директорию с исходниками, которые необходимо проверить. А как сделать что-то подобное с *Clang Static Analyzer*?

Comment: Так может у вас вопрос в том, что непонятно как пользоваться CSA, а не в том как прикрутить к студии? Еще, пожалуйста, поясните подробнее что значить "прикрутить", то есть как именно это должно работать.

Comment: Я не правильно выразился, в настоящий момент я действительно не понимаю, как пользоваться CSA. В идеале хотелось бы запускать его с указанием папки с исходниками и указывать, на какие типы ошибок реагировать, как, например, в cppcheck, после этого парсить результаты. Но меня устроит любой рабочий вариант :)

Comment: Скорректируйте свой вопрос, оставьте только одну тему

Answer (score 4):

Для начала можно зайти на [официальный сайт со сборками LLVM](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html) и взять оттуда готовый установщик `Clang for Windows`. При установке оставить флажок `Do not add LLVM to system PATH` на месте. После установки (64-битного варианта) в папке `C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin` среди прочего будут лежать `clang++.exe` и `clang-check.exe`.

Открываем студию. Создаем пустой консольный проект. Создаем файл `main.cpp` в котором с ходу простреливаем себе ногу (для целей демонстрации):

```
int main()
{
    int items[4];
    int item{items[5]};
}
```

Теперь попробуем прикрутить анализ к сборке. Анализатору необходимо знать, какие файлы и с какими параметрами должны собираться. К сожалению, параметры сборки из обычного студийного проекта он извлекать не умеет (даже при использовании в проекте тулсета llvm). Но их можно указать через файл `compile_commands.json`. Этот файл может быть сгенерирован cmake или его вполне можно написать и руками:

```
[
    {
        "directory": "D:/Projects/ConsoleApplication26/ConsoleApplication26/"
    ,   "command": "\"C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe\" -c -O0 -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -fvisibility=hidden -fno-rtti -o main.o main.cpp"
    ,   "file": "main.cpp"
    }
]
```

Формат файла достаточно простой - массив объектов с информацией для сборки каждого файла:

- `directory` - рабочая директория для запуска компилятора; тут указывается директория, где лежит `main.cpp`
- `command` - команда для компиляции `main.cpp`
- `file` - имя файла, который должен компилироваться, т.е. `main.cpp`

Теперь научим студию вызывать анализатор используя этот файл. Выделяем в `Solution Explorer` файл `compile_commands.json`, вызываем контекстное меню, выбираем пункт `Properties`. В открывшимся окне свойств меняем тип файла на `Custom Build Tool`

[image: тип файла]

Нажимаем `Применить` и идем заполнять настройки в появившемся разделе `Custom Build Tool`:

[image: настройки сборки]

Запускаем `clang-check` с опцией `analyze` для проведения анализа и именем файла (который прописан в `compile_commands.json`). В качестве входящего файла указываем `main.cpp` чтобы анализ перезапускался при его изменении. В качестве выходящего будет xml файл с отчетом (бесполезный).

Собираем файл `compile_commands.json` (или весь проект), получаем результат анализа:

[image: результаты анализа]

Comment: А как можно распространить этот подход на все файлы проекта? Я так понимаю в первую очередь всё анализируемое должно уметь собираться clang'ом, т.е. нельзя просто взять и вырвать отдельный файл для анализа, т.к. он может иметь зависимости.

Comment: @alexolut Можно оставить в проекте только одну единицу трансляции. Ну или писать (генерировать) описания для всех этих файлов в `compile_commands.json`.

Comment: зафигачить всё в один файл в смысле? :) не очень юзерфрендли метод.

Comment: @alexolut Я имел ввиду перейти на использование SCU (single compilation unit) проектов. В нормальном виде это подразумевает, что все пишется в виде header-only библиотеки, которая инклюдится в единственную единицу трансляции проекта (т.е. в проекте только один .cpp, а в нем одна строчка `#include...`). В ненормальном виде это может быть что угодно от зафигачивания всего в один файл, до .cpp файл, который включает в себя все остальные .cpp файлы. Ну или можно как-нибудь генерировать `compile_commands.json`, включающий инфо для всех .cpp файлов как-нибудь автоматически.

Comment: на всякий случай поинтересуюсь, не будет ли у Вас решения для [схожего вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47633867/3240681) под другую IDE?

Comment: @alexolut Ну в общих чертах решение будет таким же - делать `compile_commands.json` и запускать clang-check. По идее это все можно делать напрямую из командной строки. Но ничего конкретного по поводу билдера сказать не могу - с наследием Borland дела давно не имел.

Comment: ну а как быть с тем, что там имеются свои нестандартные расширения, которые clang просто не поймёт?

Comment: @alexolut Наверное отказываться от этих нестандартных расширений и по возможности писать на ISO С++, или как-то их изолировать.

Comment: Как платная альтернатива - https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/ который в бекграунде крутит clang-tidy.

Answer (score 0):

На текущий день существует расширение [Clang Power Tools](https://www.clangpowertools.com/) для Visual Studio, с помощью которого можно достаточно удобно выполнять различные проверки *clang-tidy* (при желании с автоисправлениями) или выполнять автоматическое форматирование исходников *clang-format*.

Для проведения статического анализа кода нужно [добавить проверку](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/index.html) `clang-analyzer*` и запустить *clang-tidy*. Сделать это можно различными способами. Самый простой - написать `clang-analyzer*` в окне настроек *Clang Power Tools → Tidy → Custom Checks*. Задать режим *"Use checks from: custom checks"*. После чего через контектное меню файла, проекта или даже всего решения запустить проверку:

> [image: меню]

Результат проверки будет выведен в стандартной вкладке *"Error List" Visual Studio*, где выводятся предупреждения и ошибки при рядовой компиляции.